# Spring JPA multiple EntityManagerFactory defined but still repositories accessing only one database

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Everyone says its really easy to use Spring JPA but i wonder why its so complicated with **multiple datasources.**
I am trying to access 3 different databases and i have defined corresponding config files for the same and seperate Repositories as well.

Spring is calling all three EntityManagerFactories but when i access them in Service layer, i have access to same db all the time.

Is there anyway to **verify if Autowired Repository is pointing to correct database**?

My **1st db config**

```
  @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xx.xx.xx.xx", entityManagerFactoryRef = "orangeEntityManagerFactory ", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerthree")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class TestDbConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}")
    String driverClassName = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
    String url = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
    String userName = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
    String password = "";
    @Autowired
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;


    @Bean(name = "orangeEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "orangeEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url)
                .driverClassName(driverClassName).username(userName)
                .password(password).build());

        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(R.orange_PACKAGE);
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("orangePersistenceUnit");
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "orangeTransactionManager")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerThree() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

}
```

****2nd db config ****

```
 @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xx.xx.xx.xx", entityManagerFactoryRef = "cscheloEntityManagerFactory ", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagertwo")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class cscDbConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasourcecschelo.driver-class-name}")
    String driverClassName = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasourcecschelo.url}")
    String url = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasourcecschelo.username}")
    String userName = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasourcecschelo.password}")
    String password = "";
    @Autowired
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    // @Bean(name = "cscheloDataSource")
    // public DataSource dataSource() {
    // return DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url)
    // .driverClassName(driverClassName).username(userName)
    // .password(password).build();
    // }

    @Bean(name = "cscheloEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "cscheloEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url)
                .driverClassName(driverClassName).username(userName)
                .password(password).build());

        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(R.cscDB_PACKAGE);
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("cscheloPersistenceUnit");
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManagertwo")
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerTwo() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

}
```

**3rd db config**

```
  @Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "xx.xx.xx.xx", entityManagerFactoryRef = "harvEntityManagerFactory ", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerOne")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class HarvDbConfig {

    @Value("${spring.datasourceHarvhelo.driver-class-name}")
    String driverClassName = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasourceHarvhelo.url}")
    String url = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasourceHarvhelo.username}")
    String userName = "";
    @Value("${spring.datasourceHarvhelo.password}")
    String password = "";
    @Autowired
    JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter;

    @Bean(name = "HarvEntityManager")
    public EntityManager entityManager() {
        return entityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    }

    @Bean(name = "HarvEntityManagerFactory")
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        factoryBean.setDataSource(DataSourceBuilder.create().url(url)
                .driverClassName(driverClassName).username(userName)
                .password(password).build());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(R.HarvnDB_PACKAGE);
        factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("HarvPersistenceUnit");
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerOne() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }

}
```

**My Repositories**

```
    @Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select * from orders  where id=?1", nativeQuery = true)
    Order getOrders(Long id);

    @Query(value = "REPLACE INTO order  ", nativeQuery = true)
    void replaceIntoOrder(Order order);

    Order findById(Long id);

}

@Repository
public interface cscOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from v_orders  where old_id=?1 and ordertype_id=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Order findByIdndType(int id, int type);
}

@Repository
public interface HarvOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select * from v_orders  where old_id=?1 and ordertype_id=?2", nativeQuery = true)
    Order findByIdndType(int id, int type);
}
```

and this is how i am trying to access them

```
 @Service
public class OrderService extends AbstractService<Order> {

    @Autowired
    OrderRepository orangeOrderRepository;
    @Autowired
    HarvOrderRepository ngheloOrderRepository;
    @Autowired
    cscOrderRepository cscheloOrderRepository;

    @Override
    public Order findById(Long id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
        int idToBePassed = 123223;
        int type = 1;

        Order ngheloOrder = ngheloOrderRepository.findByIdndType(idToBePassed,
                type);
        Order cscheloOrder = cscheloOrderRepository.findByIdndType(
                idToBePassed, type);
```

As can be seen in code i am autowiring all 3 repositories from 3 db's ,i want to fetch data from one db and insert in another(as per my requirement) but when i tried accessing **cscheloOrderRepository.findByIdndType(
                idToBePassed, type);** it says table xyz do not exist ,because it is not accessing the right EntityManagerFactory settings.

Moreover i do not know how to Autowire EntityManagerFactory manually in Repositories,i tried with PersistentContext but got exception that bean not found.

Please provide your valuable feedback. how can i resolve this problem , Thanks.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa-examples/blob/master/spring-data-jpa-example/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/example/repository/custom/UserRepositoryImpl.java

Comment: @jay it did not help unfortunately

Comment: is your repositories in the same package ?

Comment: @Roxy After almost a year, did you have a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the entityManagerFactory bean in the @EnableJpaRepositories's attribute 'entityManagerFactoryRef', the EntityManagerFactory bean with the name entityManagerFactory found in the context is automatically wired. It's all in Spring Data JPA reference doc http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/

> **entityManagerFactoryRef**: Explicitly wire the EntityManagerFactory to be used with the
>   repositories being detected by the repositories element. Usually used
>   if multiple EntityManagerFactory beans are used within the
>   application. If not configured we will automatically lookup the
>   EntityManagerFactory bean with the name entityManagerFactory in the
>   ApplicationContext.

try this:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "xxx.xxx.xxx.entitiesfordb1", 
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerForDB1", 
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerForDB1"
)
```

Comment: L i think we are suppose to define repositories in basePackages and not entities .

Answer (score 1):

Please see below example

http://fabiomaffioletti.me/blog/2014/04/15/distributed-transactions-multiple-databases-spring-boot-spring-data-jpa-atomikos/

Basically, your repositories need to be on the different packages. Other than the distributed transactions, this is what you want , I guess..

Answer (score 0):

persistence.xml file containing this

```
  <persistence-unit name="MyAppPostgresPU">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/PostgresPool_test</jta-data-source>
    <class>model.MyThing</class>
  </persistence-unit>

  <persistence-unit name="MyAppMySQLPU">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/MySQLPool_test</jta-data-source>
    <class>model.MyThing</class>
  </persistence-unit>
```

the code

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName= "MyAppMySQLPU")
EntityManager emMySQL;
@PersistenceContext(unitName= "MyAppPostgresPU")
EntityManager emPostgres;

emMySQL.persist(thing);
emPostgres.persist(thing);
```